# How to draw lines over custom keyboard like in SWYPE?

Tags: android, draw

I am working on a project where I am creating something similar to the SWYPE keyboard in android. I am not getting an idea about how to draw lines over the keyboard. I have gone though the FingerPaint sample and know how to draw lines in a canvas, but not getting an idea as to how to draw over the keyboard, like in swype and to also press buttons on the soft input keyboard again like in SWYPE.

I can give additional info/post code somewhere about current work done.

Comment: I have started with the LatinIME sample and modifying that. I have overridden the onTouchEvent in the LatinKeyboardView and am able to draw the lines, but the issue now is that the keyboard acts like an image instead of a keyboard.

Comment: here is the link to current code: http://pastie.org/pastes/4222869/text?key=adqh1dcmwztjswmaimazkg

Comment: Ok, so as of now I have figured out how to draw lines and still have the keyboard. The (possibly) last bug is about the popup window that remains up even when i finish drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to use the fingerPaint example and overriding the onMotionTouch() method.
Use the invalidate() function to have the drawing displayed while moving the finger.

If anyone needs more clarifications, i can see if i could post my code online.

R

Comment: Hi, could you please post some code or the entire `LatinKeyboardView` class like above. I am trying to do something similar but not able to do it.